# new returns NULL when initializing static global variable in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, new-operator

I'm working on integrating rLog with our code base, and I'm noticing a problem on Windows that I don't have on linux.  In a header file I have a static variable that gives me a "verbose" logging channel (one up from debug basically), defined thusly:

```
static RLogChannel *rlog_verbose = DEF_CHANNEL("verbose", Log_Debug);
```

There's no problem with this on Linux, but on Windows I get an error as soon as the application starts.

I've tracked it down to this line in the rLog library:

```
RLogChannel *rlog::GetComponentChannel(const char *component, const char* path, LogLevel levl) {
...
if(!gRootChannel)
    gRootChannel = new RLogChannel( "", level );
...
}
```

The problem is that the call to new is returning a NULL pointer, which goes unchecked
and the program promptly crashes when it's accessed.   Are there rules related to allocating memory in a global context on Windows that I'm not away of?

Edit: I'm pretty sure this must be something related to the order of initialization of static objects.  I wanted to be sure that I wasn't missing something obvious re: memory allocation on Windows.  Thanks all!

Comment: `new` cannot return null. Do you mean it throws an exception?

Comment: Have you checked if the code actually is executed or is gRootChannel just NULL somewhere else?

Comment: What is the connection between these two pieces of code? In the first one the variable name is `rlog_verbose`, in the second it is `gRootChannel`. What's the connection? Is there any?

Comment: Sorry, updated to be a little clearer, that snippet of code is in a function that's called as a result of using the DEF_CHANNEL macro.

@GMan: I wasn't aware that new threw an exception, good to know, but I'm seeing an invalid write to 0x00000000, so it must be something other than the new call.  Probably something with the order of static initializers...

Comment: @GMan: In Visual Studio 6 new does return NULL in case of error.
@gct: Which version of VS are you using?

Comment: @Ralph: I go by the standard, not a (poor) implementation of it. I'm still at a loss why anyone would use such an ancient, poor-compliance, bad-performing compiler.

Comment: @Gman: most people using an ancient, poor compliant compiler (I'm not sure if it performs poorly) is because they have an existing codebase that uses it. I'd guess that most of those people would rather move to something newer, but getting the old code to work on something newer can be a lot of work.

Comment: @Michael: Bah, I forget about that; I'm always writing new code. And from what I've heard, the performance was merely okay. I don't know much though; at that time I was a mere tot trying to print "Hello, World".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

are you sure its returning null. It might be the whole static initializer thing. The order of static initializer invocations is not defined from file to file. If you have static code that is using rlog_verbose then gRootCHannel might well be NULL simply because the initializer hasn't been called yet.

Answer (score 1):

`new` doesn't return NULL. it throws an `std::bad_alloc` exception if it fails. This happens even if its in the static data initialization which is actually called in the entry point CRT function which later calls `main()`.

The NULL you're seeing is probably there since the `new` was never called. To verify that it actually gets called you can simply place a breakpoint on the static initialization and see when it occurs.

Comment: Very good to know, I'm guessing this is some sort of static initialization problem, I just have very little windows experience so I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

`new` doesn't return null. So your problem must be that you are using `rlog_verbose` before your static initializer executes.  It's possible that your static initializer is *never* executing. (that would be a link problem)

You need to start up a debugger and set a break on your static initializer, and on `main`, and on the line of code that is crashing and just see what is happening.  If you step over the crash does it work? is the crash happening before `main`?